# iframe in IE9 doesn't recognize a cookie until after I've hit F12

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, iframe, brightcove

Yes, I sounds crazy to me too. Pull my hair out, bang my head on the keyboard crazy. That's why I'm here begging :)

Hopefully this isn't too brief:

I'm embedding an iframe in a WordPress admin-side add new entry form. Prior to the iframe being displayed in a meta box a cookie is set. The iframe looks for that cookie as a means of authentication. If the cookie has a particular value the user does not have to signin to the service provided by the iframe. They are automatically logged in. However, the only way I can get the iframe to see the cookie is to hit F12 and then refresh the page. Once I do that the auto-login happens as expected. Obviously, hitting F12 is not an optimal UX :)

Everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

The only other detail I've noticed is that even once I get the iframe to see the cookie and authenticate the button for selecting a file to upload doesn't work. I click it and it's dead.

Finally, the iframe "widget" is from FileMobile. It's an uploader to Brightcove. That detail probably doesn't matter but if you've read this far I'm sure you're curious.

Again, everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox.